# Why a specific application is not opening from the task scheduler when the user is logged off?

Tags: vb.net, windows, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, windows-task-scheduler

I am having a problem while trying to schedule a task when the user account is logged off. My program works fine when the the user account is logged on.

I am scheduling a task to using an automation executable file which open some applications, write the log and mail the log file by closing all the application windows, and it is working perfect.

The applications accesses oracle db and are built using vb.net.

The problem is scheduling the task when the user account is logged on it is running and publishing the email perfectly, but when the user account logged off, it is opening only some applications which I see in my log file in mail. Could you please help?

I have enabled the option "Run whether the user is logged on or not" and checked the option "Run with higher Privileges".

Comment: Try scheduling the app with runas, e.g. like runas.exe /profile /user:YOURDOMAIN\YourUser yourapp.exe. If still NOK, your app might try to interact with the desktop (explorer.exe 1st copy) which doesn't exist. If now OK your app can't run under inherited user (e.g. you try to use %appdata% folder or similar) or with low trust level

Comment: @Mark Sorry dear friend... I did not understand what is this runas is? is there any link so that you can explain me better..?

Comment: No worries. Windows built-in app to run software under the name of a(nother) user. Here's a link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx

Comment: What kind of applications are the ones that are not running?  Are they console applications or winforms applications?  Do they have a user interface?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The applications I am running are winforms. yes they include UI...

Comment: @Mark I am not understanding how runas command is related to my question! to run the command only I have to login to the system. But my question is to run my job without longing to the system. I want to schedule my job every day on specific time where the system is powered on and any or none of the users are logged into the system.

Comment: @Mark This is my commamd:  **runas /netonly /user:myserver.com\padmin "Application_Server_Test.exe D:\servertest"** this is executing my script in local..!!

Comment: The thing is, something is probably wrong with your app, we need to figure out what. I don't get what do you mean by your last comment, please explain. BTW, if your app has UI it cannot display without a logged in user as windows to display need to have desktop (which is, again, explorer.exe running and for that, you need a logged in user)

Comment: @Mark All my applications I am opening are windows applications and I am not performing any operation on them except opening and closing. I use automation is to confirm are all ma applications are opening perfectly, to per form this i have done a perl automation, and converted it to .exe and scheduled it. I have total 7 of such applications in that five works fine in any circumstances(user logged-in/out, user secession active or locked), but the remaining two are not working fine when the user is logged out.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure then I can help as there can be many issues. What I would do is: 1-try adding debug info(maybe even before every line of code) to see if app starts and fails or not even called, and if fails, where. 2-if it doesn't work, as there are other apps which are OK, I would truncate the code, first, having the core elements only (hello world level), then adding back functionality one by one to figure out which part of the app denies it running without an active user. I'm sorry I can't give you more but this is not 'something common' if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Mark Yep buddy, I have done the same thing before. I have come to know that the code to open the application **\`App_file_path\`;** itself is not executing. :( but in other cases it is performing as needed.

Comment: Same version of same references are used? Ie same "code behind"? My feeling is this should be something trivial but hiding very well :)

Comment: @Mark Yep buddy... Same version of same references are used, everything for all the scenarios remain the same.

Comment: Knowing this, I'm puzzled. I'd stay with what I recommended previously. Either a new/empty app and adding code piece by piece or truncating existing to see which item compromises the behaviour. Sorry I can't help more but even sitting with you at your computer would be a 50-50 chance, and/or several days. Either way, let the community know please when you figured out what goes boom.

Comment: Sorry buddy. I am saying that the applications(which I am using in my script) themselves is not able to open when the user is logged out. The applications I am using might have some problem in opening in this condition.